# Looking for information on a programming language called WhatDoesItDo

Tags: operating-system, motorola, 6800

I am looking for information on a training language called "WhatDoesItDo". It was used in 1978 at Austin Community College on a Motorola 6800 CPU.

If anyone has any information, I would appreciate it very, very much.

Comment: You may get better answers at https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @NateEldredgeThank you for the info.

Comment: I see you posted there and got an answer: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15876/looking-for-information-on-a-programming-language-called-whatdoesitdo.  In such cases it is nice to add a direct link to the new question from your original question.  Otherwise someone might come along, find this question, and spend a lot of time writing an answer, without knowing it has already been answered on the other site.